# How to upload files and folders to AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I use **SSH** to connect to my **Ubuntu instance**. With SSH I can administer files and folders on the instance, but how do I upload files and folders from my local machine to the instance?

Is it possible to do right from SSH session, without using SFTP clients?

Answer (score 13):

Just to add a bit more detail to the scp command (included in OSx and most linux/unix):

```
scp -i myssh.pem local_file username@200.200.200.200:/home/username
```

Obviously - replace the pem file with the one used for ssh access.  Obviously replace "username" and "200.200.200.." with valid values for your setup.

Comment: With regards to the local file, I get:

No such file or directory

Answer (score 10):

You can try [kitten](https://github.com/hoffa/kitten) utility which is a wrapper around boto3. You can easily upload/download files and run commands on EC2 server or on multiple servers at once for that matter.

```
kitten put -i ~/.ssh/key.pem cat.jpg /tmp [SERVER NAME][SERVER IP]
```

Where server name is e.g ubuntu or ec2-user etc.

This will upload cat.jpg file to /tmp directory of server

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned already, I've used WinSCP, which logs me in as "ec2-user" - then make sure to adjust that user's permissions via SSH. Example:

```
chown -R ec2-user /path/to/files
```

(Authenticate as the root user first.)

Whatever folder or files you need to edit via WinSCP, allow permissions on them (otherwise you will get a permission denied error when trying to upload/edit files in WinSCP).

Comment: This worked. But as a noob I can't tell if there are any security issues that would be associated with this solution. Any thoughts from the community?

Answer (score 5):

you cannot copy files using ssh. you can use scp/sftp.

scp if you are on linux or [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) if you are on windows

Comment: I found out [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) to be way faster than WinSCP for uploading files to my EC2 instances, if that might help.

Comment: @Viccari could you mention the steps to use filezilla with ec2

Comment: @HarpreetBhatia should be straightforward. You need to add your keypair to FileZilla, configure your username/password and hostname. That should do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
scp -i yourkeypair.pem source destination
```

Answer (score 3):

This Works Fine

```
scp -r -i myssh.pem /local/directory remote_username@10.10.0.2:/remote/directory
```

-r for recursive

Answer (score 0):

You could also install and set up an FTP Server, which will allow you to set up users, and directories for them to upload to. That being said, I've upvoted the above because scp/sftp is the ideal method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install webmin and user the file manager (java plugin) from your browser.

//Go to home folder

```
cd ~
```

//Download the latest version

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin-1.660-1.noarch.rpm
```

//install

```
sudo rpm -U webmin-1.660-1.noarch.rpm
```

//Change default password of root user
passwd

Finally, open port 10000 in the security groups

Then, log into

```
https://server_name:10000
```

with user:root password:what_you_set_before